# AR image tracker at distant?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, image-recognition, vuforia

I am working on an Augmented Reality app that requires image tracker placed at a distant. A target would be a bill board or scoreboard in a basketball game. I have tried Qualcomm's Vuforia SDK, it seems it only works when the marker is placed within 3 feet from the camera. When you move further, I think it loses detail and AR engine is not able to recognize the tracker any more.

In theory, if the marker is large and bright enough, and with a clearly defined details and border markings for tracking purpose, should it not work?

Also, is there anyway for an AR app to recognize ANY flat surface like a table or hardwood floor with variety of colors and textures, as long as it's a flat surface. Typical applications would be virtual keyboard or chess board.

thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

AR is about recognition markers, not shape. AR engine input is image from camera and there is no way to determine shape from it, so answer for Your second question is: NO.

PS: In my case (iOS) default marker is detected from about 1,5m and can be tracked to about 4m. I think, that resolution of the camera is important thing and can affect on tracking effiency.

Answer (score 0):

The experience we have is that a marker in the size of about 20x20cm is readable by the Vuforia SDK in about 5 meter distance. That seems to be the very limit.